# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR | Fetch string between two delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a string `Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure |C`. I want to fetch the sub-string after organization name (after two '..' characters) and before pipe character. So the output string should be - `Truck/Equipment Failure`.
Can you please help.

I have been trying forming regexp like this but doesn't seem working.

`select regexp_substr('Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure |C', '[^.]+',1,2) from dual;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure |C',
                      '([^.]+)\|',
                      1,
                      1,
                      NULL,
                      1)
  FROM DUAL;
```

**EDIT:**  This will match exactly two dots followed by one or more characters other than a `|` till the end of string.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure',
                      '\.{2}([^|]+)',
                      1,
                      1,
                      NULL,
                      1)
  FROM DUAL;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/324)

Comment: Thanks Kaushik for quick response. This works but there is one problem.
If the input string is `Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure`, that is, if it is without pipe substring, it returns NULL. In that case it should return `Truck/Equipment Failure`. Can you please help with this.

Comment: @AmitJagtap : So it means in some cases you don't have pipe. What should we rely on then? end of string ? Are these two  the only cases or do you have any other format?

Comment: There are only two cases:
`Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure |C` and `Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure`.

Comment: @AmitJagtap : You are welcome. It is always better to include all cases to expect  while asking the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: hi is there any way to this in oracl 10g

Answer (score 2):

Classic SUBSTR + INSTR option:

```
SQL> with test as (select 'Organization, INC..Truck/Equipment Failure |C' col from dual)
  2  select substr(col, instr(col, '..') + 2,
  3                     instr(col, '|') - instr(col, '..') - 2
  4                ) result
  5  from test;

RESULT
------------------------
Truck/Equipment Failure

SQL>
```