# Return value between two characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a code like:

```
SELECT config_id FROM config
```

Which returning me strings:

```
1S100I20C1P
1S8I9C1P
1S80I48C1P
```

I just need to get number between S and I, for 1 string its gonna be 100, for second string its gonna be 8 etc.
I know regexp should work here, but can't really find the matching pattern.
Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle REGEXP\_SUBSTR | Fetch string between two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027346/oracle-regexp-substr-fetch-string-between-two-delimiters)

Answer (score 4):

This is, actually, the 2nd *number* in that string (`result1`). Or, use `substr` + `instr` combination (`result2`):

```
SQL> with config (config_id) as
  2    (select '1S100I20C1P' from dual union all
  3     select '1S8I9C1P'    from dual union all
  4     select '1S80I48C1P'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select
  7    config_id,
  8    regexp_substr(config_id, '\d+', 1, 2) result1,
  9    substr(config_id, instr(config_id, 'S') + 1,
 10                      instr(config_id, 'I') - instr(config_id, 'S') - 1
 11          ) result2
 12  from config;

CONFIG_ID   RESULT1     RESULT2
----------- ----------- -----------
1S100I20C1P 100         100
1S8I9C1P    8           8
1S80I48C1P  80          80

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) which contains letters `S` and `I` within the pattern such as

```sql
SELECT config_id,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(config_id,'(.*S)(.*)(I.*)','\2') AS extractedString
  FROM config
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=24afbbacf07cad68dd4caa203c306fcc)</kbd>